# save Large RasterBrick to file for later use

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a Large RasterBrick, created through compiling a large number of .nc files and then manipulating in a few ways (cropping, collapsing, naming layers). I want to save this brick to a file on my laptop, so that I can access it without having to import all data and manipulate anew.

How do I do this? I think it should involve writeRaster, but I'm not sure how to specify the options.

My RasterBrick is 18 by 25, with 14975 layers, each named with the relevant date.

I tried this code from [Save multi layer RasterBrick to harddisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936547/save-multi-layer-rasterbrick-to-harddisk):

```
outfile <- writeRaster(windstack_mn, filename='dailywindgrid.tif', format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE,options=c("INTERLEAVE=BAND","COMPRESS=LZW"))
```

However, this code produce a tif file that holds a single 18 by 25 layer. I *think* it saved only the 1st layer of my RasterBrick, because if I bring in the saved .tif file and plot it, it looks identical to plotting the 1st layer of the original RasterBrick.

Answer (score 3):

Did you look at `outfile`? Can you show it to us?

You should show what you do to "bring in the saved .tif". I am guessing that you do

```
raster('dailywindgrid.tif')
```

whereas you should be doing

```
brick('dailywindgrid.tif')
```

Comment: Thank you! You are right, I was using raster() and when I use brick('dailywindgrid.tif') I do indeed bring in an 18 x 25 brick w/ 14975 layers. This matches what I was trying to export, though I can't immediately check the precise values, as it will take ~10 hours to re-load the original data for comparison. However, I CAN see right away that the layer names were not saved w/in the .tif file. I don't suppose there is any way to save the layer names, along w/ the layers of grid data (presuming the latter is indeed correct)?

Comment: To save the layer names you would need to use the ".grd" format

Comment: Thanks, once I used the raster format this worked. I mentioned this in an answer  below, to put everything together for a future reader. One more question, if you'll answer -- what do the specified options do? The help for writeRaster does not even mention the option  INTERLEAVE, and does not define COMPRESS or  the options for COMPRESS.

Answer (score 0):

The comment/answer fr/ Robert solves my issue, with the one addition that one needs to specify the raster format. So I  am now saving the file with this code:

```
writeRaster(StackName, filename='FileNAme.grd', format="raster", overwrite=TRUE,options=c("INTERLEAVE=BAND","COMPRESS=LZW"))
```

And that .grd file  can later  be opened using this code:

```
ImportName <- brick("FileNAme.grd")
```